# How to run Xamarin for Asp.Net On Mac without using sudo

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, xamarin, mono

Basically I installed Mono Framework, then Xamarin Studio.

Created a Asp.Net Application. Ran it. Got this error:

```
Application Exception
System.SystemException
Error running mcs: Cannot find the specified file

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.
Exception stack trace:
  at Mono.CSharp.CSharpCodeCompiler.CompileFromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00135] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System/Microsoft.CSharp/CSharpCodeCompiler.cs:216 
  at Mono.CSharp.CSharpCodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00011] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System/Microsoft.CSharp/CSharpCodeCompiler.cs:136 
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00014] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System/System.CodeDom.Compiler/CodeDomProvider.cs:111 
  at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) [0x002e8] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/AssemblyBuilder.cs:822 
  at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/AssemblyBuilder.cs:731 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group, System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00264] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildManager.cs:826 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildInner (System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x0011c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildManager.cs:451 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Build (System.Web.VirtualPath vp) [0x00056] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildManager.cs:396 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00040] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildManager.cs:989 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.String virtualPath) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildManager.cs:972 
  at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.InitType (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x0016b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplicationFactory.cs:417 
Version Information: 4.0.4 ((detached/cb6d6b2 Thu Sep 10 07:14:07 EDT 2015); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
Powered by Mono
```

It feels like permission since it can build and I can run console application fine.

So I tried ran Xamarin Studio App from terminal using sudo. Then the problem is gone.

However I couldn't believe this is the right solution. Wondering if anyone knows how to run this properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Find the location of "mcs" using the terminal

```
which mcs
```

It should be /usr/local/bin/mcs, which is not in Xamarin's path. Fix this by linking mcs to /usr/bin

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/mcs /usr/bin
```

Comment: /usr/local/bin/mcs doesn't exist as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I installed the latest updates from Xamarin studio and problem was resolved.

To do so, go to the *Xamarin Studio* menu --> *Check for Updates...*. You'll see the list of available updates. Download and install them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.